# QGIS/GRASS: forecast slope variation in slope by a new road

Tags: qgis, slope

For preliminary project purposes, I wonder if there is a way to forecast and calculate with QGIS and/or GRASS the variation of slope dued by new road, starting with terrain DEM and a project sketch of the road:
[image: road section]
(translation: Piano di campagna pendenza 50/60% = original slope 50/60
              stradello larghezza 2,50m = road width).

Could be enough to made this task even in the maximum slope line.

Comment: First of all, there are rules when designing roads. If the cross section of the terrain is higher, the embankment of the road is smaller. On that value of cross section, the embankment should be zero. Thats why road designing is very hard to automatize. If I understand the question.